# How to parse events from a public Google Calendar with Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a public Google Calendar link (which I do not manage), and I would like to extract data from it to my python program. (From there I will myself process the data).

Basically, given a url to a public Google Calendar, I want to parse the events. No need to add or delete events, just read the events and their info. I don't see a reason to log in to my Google account because anyone with the url can view said Calendar from their browser with no sign-in needed.

Couldn't find anything on the web that does specifically this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **need** to use authentication. There simply is no way around this. There are several reasons for this, but the main one is that the Google Calendar API has usage limits.

If there is no way to identify the account performing the request, you could create an app that spams the API with so much requests you bring down the Google Calendar API for everyone. Attaching authentication to the requests allows Google to track the usage.

You should use a service account created specifically for this. The best documentation about service accounts and how to use them in python is [this one](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python).

Combining [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) for the Calendar API with the one linked above should get you started.

Note, if you are performing a lot of requests, you might hit the limits mentioned above. You will need to use what is called exponential backoff. The principle is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff). If you want to know about why to use a random value, see [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-avoid-a-self-inflicted-ddos-attack-cre-life-lessons) nice blogpost on how to shoot yourself in the foot.